# compiling in SSH Secure Shell c++

Tags: c++, shell, ssh, compiler-errors, g++

When I run g++, it throws a couple of errors:

```
$ g++  SongStructure.cpp mtmtest.cpp Song.cpp examples/OldSongExample.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -DNDEBUG -o example

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

How to solve this and why does this happen? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What version of g++ are you using? (to check: `g++ --version`)

Answer (score 3):

You simply have a version of g++ (gcc) that does not support C++11 standard. Your can either not use C++11 (or if you don't, then don't specify `-std=c++11`), try using `-std=c++0x` that is supported by some older version of GCC when C++11 was experimental and was named C++0x, or upgrade your compiler.